# OpenMP - For loop within a while loop

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to parallelise some serial code that I have written, but I am confused on how I can deal with a while loop. The code solves a time integration, computational mechanics problem.

**( EDIT )** Firstly I am using a number of structures to store data including a matrix/vector library Meschach, with data stuctures:

```
typedef struct {
  unsigned int dim, max_dim;
  double * ve;
} VEC;

typedef struct {
  unsigned int dim, max_dim;
  double * ve;
} MAT;
```

And some user defined structures

```
typedef struct SCNI{
  MAT * B;
  VEC * Fsub ; 
  VEC * index;
     .
     . 
} SCNI;
```

I am trying to parallelize a loop but I can't seem to get an answer that doesn't depend on the number of threads used.

```
// variables
int numNode = 600;
int dim = 2;
double * Fint = malloc( dim * numNode * sizeof(double) );
VEC * stress ;
MAT * defGrad ; 
VEC * displacement = v_get(dim*numNode) ; // allocate memory for vector
VEC * matParameters = v_get(5);
VEC * mRadius = v_get(numNode); 
double intFactor;

// each point has its own SCNI structure
SCNI * scni = malloc( numnode * sizeof(SCNI) );

..................................
while ( time < t_max )
// obtain displacement at this time increment
// displacement = {a} + {b}*delta_t - where a and b are vectors
  v_mltadd(a,b,delta_t,displacement);
{

#pragma omp parallel default(none) 
\ shared(displacement,scni,matParameters,mRadius,numnode) 
\ private(i,intFactor,stressVoigt,defGrad) reduction(+:Fint[0:2*numnode]) 
{
  defGrad = m_get(dim+1,dim+1) // allocate memory for each defGrad;
  stress = v_get(5) // allocate memory for each private stress;
  memset(Fint,0,numnode*dim*sizeof(double)); // set each Fint to zero initially
// Internal force loop
#pragma omp parallel for
  for ( i = 0 ; i < numNode ; i++){
       // function call to find defGrad, using the B matrix from SCNI
       // and the vector displacement.
          calcDefGrad(defGrad,scni[i].B,displacement)
       // find stress using defGrad and the vector material parameters
          calcStress(stress,defGrad,matParamters)
       // find sub forces Fsub = scni[i].B*stress
          scni[i].Fsub = vm_mlt(scni[i].B,stress,scni[i])
       // assemble sub forces into global internal force array Fint
          assemble(Fint,scni[i].Fsub,scni[i].index,intFactor)
  }

}
....................................
}// end while loop
..................................
```

I'm not overly sure on how you share the data structures, and whether my issues stem from the matrix library I am using.

Any help/hints/tips would be much appreciated as I am very new to OpenMP, and well multi-threaded programming in general.

Comment: Most implementations will default to preserving the thread pool long enough to handle this. However, it prevents optimization between those loops, so a single parallel loop is better

Comment: Yes, more detail is required, preferably in form of a [mcve]. We cannot give you a specific recommendation without specific details. Generally: Don't guess about performance - measure.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the lack of detail, I have added some more details related to the for loop I am trying to parallelize.